# How to mock a es6/typescript module and confirm a method was called in that module using jest?

Tags: jestjs

I want to test the below module,

//module to test

```
import { methodFunction } from "./method"

export const toTest = () => {
  const response = methodFunction();
}
```

//method module

```
export const methodFunction = () => {
  return 1
}
```

How do I do this with Jest.mock()? I just want to see if methodFunction has been called. I can find examples but non work with named exports in this scenario.

//Attempt

```
jest.mock('./method', ()=> { ??? })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with

```js
import { methodFunction } from './method';

jest.mock('./method', ()=> { 
  return { methodFunction: jest.fn() }
})

describe('toTest', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    toTest()
  })

  it('should call methodFunction', () => {
    expect(methodFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
})
```

but keep in mind, that `jest.fn()` returns a function, which returns `undefined` and in order for it to return something else you'll have to use [.mockReturnValue()](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockreturnvaluevalue)

**Edit:** here's how you can mock the module partially

```js
jest.mock('./method', ()=> { 
  return {
    ...jest.requireActual('./method'),
    methodFunction: jest.fn()
  }
})
```

Comment: can you mock some functions in the module but let others run as normal? (if in ./method there was another function that I wanted to run for example)